# How to parse search results from website after having used send_keys (Python) in search bar?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

My question is related to this post: [Enter query in search bar and scrape results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58040225/enter-query-in-search-bar-and-scrape-results)

I am able to execute the answer given to this former question, but am not able to scrape data from the website that Chrome navigates to by the looping over `book`. I only found answers that would show how to scrape data from `d` in my code, but not from the search result after having used `send_keys`.

I tried to access the element but can't do so and I would like to scrape the data from the resulting website after searching for `book` and then going to the next round of the loop.

I tried:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
d = webdriver.Chrome('mypath/chromedriver.exe')
books = ['9780062457738']
for book in books:
  d.get('https://www.bol.com/nl/')
  e = d.find_element_by_id('searchfor')
  f = print(e.send_keys(book, Keys.ENTER))
```

I also tried without the `print()` function but it returns no real element if I type `f?` I get:

```
Type:        NoneType
String form: None
Docstring:   <no docstring>
```

Any help on how to parse the data of for example the author of the book, title or other information *after* having submitted a search query is very welcome!

Comment: Did you wait for the results? It might take a while to load the query, reading those elements before they are filled produces empty results.

Comment: I don't think so @nagyl. I tried with `time.sleep(2)` but still don't get a proper result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract and book title i.e. **The Subtle Art of Not Giving a F*ck** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.bol.com/nl/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.js-confirm-button>span"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#searchfor"))).send_keys("9780062457738")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[type='submit']").click()
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.product-title"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.bol.com/nl/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Accepteren']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='searchfor']"))).send_keys("9780062457738")
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']").click()
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@class, 'product-title')]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  The Subtle Art of Not Giving a F*ck
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was very useful @DebanjanB and solves my problem :)